# Create mail accounts on a server in PHP

Tags: php, email

I'm looking for a solution to create mail accounts on a server via PHP
Our host is 1and1 and and we can create mail accounts through the admin area but what we're trying to do is a PHP script that lets you do that automatically.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Subject to any limitations imposed by the permissions on the system, it is possible.

The specifics depend on how your email system determines what accounts exist. You can't programatically modify that before you know how it works.